# How can I take the first 4 characters of a column in SQL and compare it?

Tags: sql, ms-access, short

I have a Short Text column in Access called ZIP. It has to be a Short Text.

I'm trying to select the first 4 characters of each ZIP and see if it's below a certain number.

MY SQL is:

```
SELECT *
FROM [WORK]
WHERE LEFT(ZIP, 4) < 300;
```

I get an error that says "Data type mismatch in criteria expression." which I assume is because the ZIP field is a Short Text and not a number. How would I go about this?

Comment: try casting the datatypes (without us knowing your data structure thas the best quess)

Comment: @happymacarts ZIP is a string because it is a 10 digit coded ZIP code with a hyphen in the middle. I just need the first 3 of ZIP and to cast that to an INT.

Comment: Assuming only US zip codes, then comparison as numeric vs varchar will not matter; provided each zipcode in the system is well formed (Meaning 5 digits or 5 digits + '-' + 4 digits.)  the logic of evaluating a zip code using less than 300 is interesting but I guess if your after New England and Middle east  US Coast it works. (no Florida Georgia Alabama etc).  Doing "Math" on a integer zip code just seems wrong to me   It might be better to split the zip into the 1st digit next 2 and last 2.... Lastly, Why 4 positions when you're only comparing to 3?

Comment: Interesting break down of US Zip Codes: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_Code

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, I just needed to put single quotes around the 300.

I ended up with:

```
SELECT *
FROM [WORK]
WHERE LEFT(ZIP, 4) < '300' or LEFT(ZIP, 4) > '399';
```

Comment: I would caution you on attempting to compare numbers as strings.  Your ZIP field is a text field which is why you were getting a datatype mismatch when comparing it to a number (the 300 without quotes).  Instead of changing your number to a string with quotes you should cast your ZIP field as a number so you are doing a number to number comparison.

Comment: You're right. This does work, but could be potentially bad.

Comment: That's different from your original question - which John answered correctly (now deleted).

Comment: @Gustav How do I cast it if I am also taking the first 4 characters of it? It is a string because it is a coded ZIP line. So it has a dash in the middle making it a string. I take the first 4 characters before the dash.

Comment: I don't know. Your own answer added a lot of confusion. Do you wish to check for three or four characters (digits), with or without leading zeroes, and of which range?

Comment: @Gustav I want to check for 3. Sorry I was flip flopping because I was not sure myself. I need the first 3 characters of a ZIP code and to cast that to an Int. I tried CInt(LEFT(ZIP, 3) which did not work.

Comment: OK. See may answer if that should fit.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
SELECT *
FROM [WORK]
WHERE LEFT(ZIP, 3) BETWEEN '300' AND '399';
```

However, if the zip code always has three digits before the dash, in this case you would only have to check for the very first digit:

```
SELECT *
FROM [WORK]
WHERE LEFT(ZIP, 1) = '3';
```

You can also compare numerically:

```
SELECT *
FROM [WORK]
WHERE VAL(LEFT(ZIP, 3)) BETWEEN 300 AND 399;
```

and if you have Null values:

```
SELECT *
FROM [WORK]
WHERE VAL(LEFT(Nz(ZIP), 3)) BETWEEN 300 AND 399;
```

Comment: The third one is what I would need (numeric), but I get the same datatype mismatch error.

Comment: Then you have Null values for some (missing) zip codes. See edited answer.